# $http requests not working in signed apk Ionic

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, http, ionic-framework

when i run my cordova ionic app directly on android studio,it's working and send $http request perfectly.

but when i installed signed .apk,http requests doesn't work

Controller.js

```
var postObject = new Object();
postObject.User = $scope.data.username;
postObject.Secret = $scope.data.password;
  $http({
          url: 'https://example.com/',
          method: "POST",
          data: {
            'message': postObject
          }
        })
        .then(function(response) {
            $cordovaDialogs.alert('Success', 'Info', 'OK');
          },
          function(response) { 
            $cordovaDialogs.alert('Error', 'Info', 'Error');
          });
```

Config.xml

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <widget android-versionCode="1" id="com.example.abc" version="0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
        <name>Cordova project.</name>
        <description>
           Cordova project.
        </description>
        <author email="example@gmail.com" href="https://www.example.lk/">
          example
        </author>
        <content src="index.html" />
        <access origin="*" />
        <allow-intent href="*" />
        <allow-navigation href="*" />

      <engine name="android" spec="^6.2.3" />
        <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="^1.0.7" />
        <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^1.1.6" />
        <plugin name="cordova-plugin-firebase" spec="^0.1.24" />
        <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^4.0.3" />
        <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="^2.2.3" />
        <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.2" />
        <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="^2.2.1" />
```

why this happen?how can i solve this problem?

Comment: What "*does not work*" mean? Actually your issue can not be reproduced.

Comment: i cannot get `Success` message on signed apk

Comment: Seems to be an SSL certificate issue

Answer (score 0):

If the request is sent to a website with an invalid certificate the requests are dropped. This happens only for release built of your application. Check the SSL certificate and try again.